# Read text file and convert rows to Integer arrays

Tags: java, arrays

I try to read text file such this one:

```
23 0 5 6

28 1 9 5 4 0 3

90 3 6 4 7 

-1
```

I want to read and convert each row individually as integer vector and stop reading when value = -1. I get this code:

```
importjava.io.FileReader;
importjava.io.IOException;
importjava.util.Scanner;

    public class T3 {

        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

            FileReader file = new FileReader("e:\\test.txt");
            int[] integers = new int[100];    
            int[] I = new int[100];    
            int i = 0;

            try {    
                Scanner input = new Scanner(file);    
                while (input.hasNext()) {

                    integers[i] = input.nextInt();    
                    i++;    
                }    
                input.close();

            } catch (Exception e) {    
                e.printStackTrace();    
            }

            for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {    
                System.out.println(integers[i]);    
            }    
        }    
    }
```

But it is useless. Please, I need help.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers.  See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Hi,Welcome to stackoverflow,Please specify the problem you are facing

Comment: I just tried your code and it works. Perhaps you need help on how to compile java classes?

Comment: Hi, yes it work, but it reads all text file elements, and I want to read each line individually and convert it to integer array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify the while as shown below

```
Scanner s = new Scanner("file path");
while (s.hasNextLine()) {
    //read each line in the file and split the line content on the basis of space
    String[] eachLine = s.nextLine().split("\\s+");
}
```

Once you have the eachLine String array - use it to initialize the Integer vector. Also, following this approach you can avoid the `-1` which you are putting explicitly to tell the `Scanner` the end of line/ file/ input.

Use `eachLine.lenght` to define the length of each `Vector`.

For example,

```
28 1 9 5 4 0 3

90 3 6 4 7

Scanner s = new Scanner("file path");
while (s.hasNextLine()) {
    String[] eachLine = s.nextLine().split("\\s+");
    //import java.util.Arrays;
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(eachLine));
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, your code is really great. However, there is a problem which is the code does not read the first element in all lines except the first line. I'll grateful for any idea. Thanks

Comment: It works fine. Check whether you using proper array index while fetching the values. Array indexed start from `0`. for example - `eachLine[0]` is there or not.

Comment: Thank you very much indeed, I try it, but it still the same problem. Here the example:
the text file data is:

90 1 3 6 5  ,  20 0 5 6 7 8 11 10  ,   60 3 8 9 9    

after applying your code the data become:
       eachLine[0]=[90, 1, 3, 6, 5] ,
       eachLine[1]=[, 0, 5, 7, 8, 11, 10] ,
       eachLine[2]=[,60, 3 8, 9, 9]

Comment: @John if the edit does not help. please feel free to create another question.

Answer (score 0):

```
Path path = get("test.txt");
List<int[]> list = new ArrayList<>();

try (BufferedReader reader = newBufferedReader(path)) {
    String line;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null && !line.contains("-1")) {
        if (line.isEmpty()) continue;

        String[] strings = line.split(" ");
        int[] integers = new int[strings.length];

        for (int i = 0; i < strings.length; i++) {
            integers[i] = parseInt(strings[i]);
        }
        list.add(integers);
    }
}
```

Edit:

```
import static java.nio.file.Files.newBufferedReader;
import static java.lang.Integer.parseInt;
import static java.nio.file.Paths.get;
```

Comment: Thank you, but I always have error with "get".

Comment: @John you need to add static imports.

Comment: Thank you very much indeed, it's still a problem shown in 
"new BufferedReader(path)", it ask me to change type of path to reader.
Many thanks

Comment: @John there is no space after `new` in my code because it's part of the static method name in `Files` class.

Answer (score -1):

Lets get you on the right track.

I think the problem with your code is that you assume each next character is an integer. Which is not the case as you have spaces as delimiter.

An approach I would do is read in line by line with the nextLine method. Then use a StringTokenizer to cut all integers apart from eachother by specifying the delimiter (space in  your case).

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

public class EgoStroker {

    private static final String DELIMITER = " ";
    private static final int MINUS_ONE = -1;
    private static final String INPUT_FILE_NAME = "input.txt";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // List containing the integers read.
        final List<Integer> integers = new ArrayList<>();
        FileReader fileReader = null;
        try {
            fileReader = new FileReader(INPUT_FILE_NAME);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException exc) {
            exc.printStackTrace();
        }
        final Scanner scanner = new Scanner(fileReader);
        // Boolean that will become false when -1 is encountered and 
        // is then used to stop the reading process.
        boolean cont = true;
        while(cont && scanner.hasNextLine()) {
          final String line = scanner.nextLine();
          final StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(line, DELIMITER);
          while(cont && tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
            final int number = Integer.parseInt(tokenizer.nextToken());
            if(number == MINUS_ONE) {
              cont = false;
            } else { 
              integers.add(number);
            }
          }
        }

        int index = 0;
        for(int integer : integers) {
            ++ index;
            System.out.println(index + ". " + integer);
        }

    }
}
```

You could replace the List with an array but you don't know in advance how many objects you will have at most so its more safe to use a dynamic List.

Comment: thank you very much, I still beginner in java, so your code looks too complicated for me.. many thanks

Comment: Hang in there, there is a lot to learn. I should have kept it more simple for a novice to understand, sorry for that.

Comment: Its pseudo, not real working code. If I would do that for every question I read on stackoverflow I would have a backlog of 100 times my lifetime.